# how to change the color of 3D firemonkey objects from different thread

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I have a cylinder

```
Cylinder1 : TCylinder;
```

and I want it to change colour when I click on it.
I've added this to the on click event

```
procedure TfrmFiremonkey.Cylinder1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Cylinder1.MaterialSource := GreenMaterial;
end;
```

The cylinder does not change colour. However it will change colour if I set Cylinder1.MaterialSource before I call the form.Show event

I suspect the reason its not showing is because Cylinder1Click is happening in a different thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that

```
procedure TfrmFiremonkey.Cylinder1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    TColorMaterialSource(Cylinder1.MaterialSource).Color := claBlue;
end;
```

Works fine